# How to split MySQL table records in half to display on each side of a page

Tags: php, mysql

To get half of MySQL table records here is what I'm using:

```
$numRows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cultures"));
$half = $numRows/2;
```

Then on each side of the page, I limit the number of records by the half of it, and on the other side I order by `DESC` instead to get the other half:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cultures ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT ".$half);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$url = "artists.php?culture=".ucfirst($row['name']);
echo '<div class="homepage_culture_item">
<a href="'.$url.'"></a>
<img src="/images/flags/'.$row['name'].'.png" style="width: 30px; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 10px;" />'.$row['name'].'
</div>
<br />';
}
```

Which works great, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

However, if there is an odd number of records in the table, I get an error:

[image]

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line *50*

It works great when there's an even number of records but if another one is added, instead of just putting it on one side, it messes up because it is probably returning an error because when you divide 15 by 2, it will be a decimal and MySQL `LIMIT` can't accept decimals (obviously). Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` is a better way to get number of rows.  Also, you need to escape data going into MySQL queries and data going into HTML, or you run the risk of SQL Injection and XSS attacks.

Comment: Yes, I know. I know **a lot** more now than I did back in January. But `SELECT COUNT(*)` never works for me :( That's why I always have to use `mysql_num_rows()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just round it down so you always get an integer. That way, a decimal won't break the query.

```
$half = floor($numRows/2);
```

You'll want to use a new `$half` value using `ceil()` on the other side to round up, so you don't skip a row in the middle.

As an aside, it might be better to do just one query returning every row, then output the rows up to `$half` on one side, then continue from that point to the end for the other side. Then you're only hitting the database once and it's easier to see what's going on.

e.g

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cultures ORDER BY name ASC");
$half   = floor(mysql_num_rows($result)/2);
$count  = 0;

// First side.
while($count <= $half
      && $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // ...
    $count++;
}

// ...

// Second side.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh so make 2 `$half` variables, one for one side and another for the other side? (and use ceil for the other side?)

Comment: @Nathan Yeah, two `$half` variables one side using `floor`, the other using `ceil`. I've updated my answer to do it a neater way though, just pulling all rows from the DB and then displaying up to the halfway point for one side, and continuing from that point on the other.

Comment: I have a question... is there still a way to show half of each records on each side? Because now it isn't even on each side and the person I'm building the site for wants an even number of cultures on each side: http://screencast.com/t/g3LkFpGw4rz

Comment: Nevermind, in the first while loop I just changed the operator to `<` and it divides them equally in half now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch all your results in a query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cultures ORDER BY name ASC");
```

And then do:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $i++
    if($i % 2){
        //echo right aligned div
        }
    else{
        //echo left aligned div
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it wouldn't work with my set up because I'm using tables (I was lazy when I did the layout so I just used tables instead :P)

Answer (score 1):

@Rich Adams I did what you did

```
<center>
<TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="500">
  <TR>
   <TD WIDTH="250">
    <TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="250">
     <TR>
      <TD WIDTH="250">
       <?php
       require_once '../../connect.php';
       mysql_select_db("DELETED!!!", $con);
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DELETED!!! ORDER BY name ASC");
       $half   = floor(mysql_num_rows($result)/2);
       $count  = 0;
       $url = $row['page'];

       while($count <= $half
                && $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href=".$row['page'].">".$row['name']."</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $count++;
       }
       ?>
      </TD>
     </TR>
    </TABLE>
   </TD>
   <TD WIDTH="250">
    <TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="250">
     <TR>
      <TD WIDTH="250">
       <?php
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href=".$row['page'].">".$row['name']."</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
       }
       mysql_close($con);
       ?>
      </TD>
     </TR>
    </TABLE>
   </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
</center>
```

But it doesn't cut the list in half and display them separately side by side.

**EDIT:** Updated my code to what I have and this table has 93 entries, is there anyway to get it split up into thirds?

Comment: It looks like it's because you're doing it all in one table and adding a new row each time. This will just print out all your records in their own row one after the other. The original question had them split up into two areas, one floated left, the other floated right. You should create each half in their own table, then position the tables side-by-side to get the same effect. So echo </table> after the first while loop, and start a new table before the second. Then edit your page's style to position those tables side by side (width:50%, float:left should do it).