# How do I get the first half of results in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 30 rows. How do I get the first ordered half (15 rows) from it?

I've tried using `SELECT TOP COUNT(*)/2 FROM table1;` but I get a syntax error.

What should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013497/how-to-split-mysql-table-records-in-half-to-display-on-each-side-of-a-page

Comment: @Sahriarrahmansupto this question is about `SQL Server` not `MySql` although there may be some actual duplicate of it elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT 
    TOP 50 PERCENT * 
FROM 
    table1;
```

Comment: thanks man, but I am going to use the `TOP 50 PERCENT`. Good to know about Ranking, but is too complex to use now.

Comment: @codemenot, ok. I've removed the Ranking reference.